# Returning a pointer which is a locally declared wchar_t

Tags: c, static, scope, return

I've read a lot of questions about returning pointers in C, but am still confused with the issue of scope.

The following code works because of the call to `malloc`, and one possible output might end up being `Wide string: StackOverflow`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

static wchar_t *get_new_ptr(char *s)
{
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    wchar_t *ws = NULL;

    ws = malloc((len + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t));
    mbstowcs(ws, s, len);
    ws[len] = '\0';

    return ws;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    wchar_t *wstr = NULL;

    if (argv[1])
        wstr = get_new_ptr(argv[1]);
    wprintf(L"Wide string: %ls\n", wstr);

    return 0;
}
```

Because `ws` is locally declared, does `wchar_t *ws` ned to be `static` to safely return the memory address to `wstr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's OK to return a local variable, it's not OK to return a pointer to a local variable.

```
int foo(void)
{
    int var = 42;
    return var;   //OK
}

int *bar(void)
{
    int var = 42;
    return &var;  //ERROR
}
```

In the case of returning a pointer, all it matters is if this pointer points to a valid place after the function returns.

In your code, you are using dynamic allocation of memory, it's OK. So the answer is, no, it's not necessary to declare it as `static`.

Comment: _In the case of returning a pointer, all it matters is if this pointer points to a valid place after the function returns._ So in your second example, the reference returned by `*bar` no longer exists after the function returns, right?

Comment: @HughMcMaster Correct.